# Use of GADMobileAds.configureWithApplicationID

Tags: ios, admob, google-advertising-id

It is written in the document I have read on Google's site that it is necessary to call `GADMobileAds.configureWithApplicationID()` at some point, as in the following code for example.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Initialize GoogleMobileAds.
    GADMobileAds.configureWithApplicationID("ca-app-pub-7876539281098811~369988223322")

    return true
}
```

But when testing the app, things seem to work fine whether this function is called or not. So is it important to call it? Does it play an identification role or something similar?

Comment: That is your Ad Unit ID, not an application ID.

Comment: Application ID and Unit ID are different. See here https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/quick-start.

My question is about the call to GADMobileAds.configureWithApplicationID().

Comment: I think it may have something to do with tracking views, clicks, revenue, etc.

Comment: OK, so I can put it or not, it won't have any impact on my revenues. Is that correct?

Comment: @Michel I'm not 100% sure. If the guide says to put it, I would. Plus, if it is indeed for tracking purposes, you should want to see the data produced from it as there are no downsides. It may also have something to do with live devices, and you don't notice a change because you're in the test phase